# what is the difference between visual studio 2015 community and professional

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

This link provide us a comparison about three versions. Apparently only TFS features is the different.  [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs)
I guess that is  more than that.Technically, Is it full featured ? 
Otherwise why would we pay $45/month for professional version. [Products](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/vs-2015-product-editions.aspx)

Comment: Well, if you check the statement **Visual Studio Community is free for individual developers, open source projects, academic research, training, education, and small professional teams. For information about the eligibility criteria "visit the Visual Studio Community product page."** at the bottom, I think in most cases you should see Professional is for companies.

Comment: Expand _all_ of the sections of the comparison table. There are a few small differences. The main differences are "Team collaboration benefits" and "Subscriber benefits". There is much more than just TFS.

Answer (score 2):

Per [this link](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs)

VS Community Usage terms

**For individuals**

Any individual developer can use Visual Studio Community to create their own free or paid apps.

**For organizations**

An unlimited number of users within an organization can use Visual Studio Community for the following scenarios: in a classroom learning environment, for academic research, or for contributing to open source projects.

For all other usage scenarios:
In non-enterprise organizations, up to five users can use Visual Studio Community. In enterprise organizations (meaning those with >250 PCs or >$1 Million US Dollars in annual revenue), no use is permitted beyond the open source, academic research, and classroom learning environment scenarios described above.

For more information, see the [Visual Studio Community license terms](https://www.visualstudio.com/support/legal/mt171547).

Answer (score 1):

Licensing is the critical point.

If you develop in the contest of an organization, you must be within limits not buying Pro license ([full details](https://www.visualstudio.com/support/legal/mt171547)), e.g. classrooms, academic, open source projects plus some.

Technically they are the same and Team Explorer is built-in. My understanding (I can be wrong) regards the licensing: the features listed are almost all accessible via web interface, so there is no technical blocker as I see it.

BTW I contribute to an [open source TFS plugin](https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator) using Community edition and found no problems.

Then you have to consider the free tier of VSTS which is a separate license. For TFS on prem, you need some CAL (Client Access License) but there is some free tier also.